# display div when "element" reaches top of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I am new to `jQuery`, I built [this](http://goo.gl/qxCRIk) page  and what I would like to happen is when a block `e.g. 2011 1 October` reaches the top of the page it displays the content for that specific `div` via the `id` or `date-attr`.

When you click on a `date` it will display the content for that date but I would like it to appear once that date block reaches the top of the page.

I have looked around the net but no luck thus far.

Comment: You need to show the relevant sections of the code in your page.  Then we can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Use scroll event to make checks for divs you are interested in - assing class for them for instance.
http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

In that event callback you can check each elements position
http://api.jquery.com/each/
To determine position element on page use
http://api.jquery.com/offset/   - top component
But don't take this value - you need to substract Window scroll position which is returned by

```
$(window).scrollTop()
```

And make some border values when element should be opened and when closed.

Answer (score 0):

As per your description that I understood, you will have to add one line of code to your "main.js" file.

```
// javascript + jquery scripts 

 // script for fading in content boxes -->
         $(".square").on("click", function() { 
            var id= $(this).attr("contentId");
            //$("#details");
            $('#details').fadeOut('slow', function() {
              $(this).html($("#" + id).html()).fadeIn('fast');
            });
        });

       // active link -->
        $(".square").click(function() {
            $(".square").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");



            $("html, body").scrollTop($(this).position().top); // THIS IS THE LINE TO BE ADDED TO SCROLL TO THE CURRENT DATE ITEM           



        });

        // fade in main content div / intro
        $(document).scroll(function () {
            var y = $(this).scrollTop();   
            if (y > 10) {
                $('.topBlock').fadeOut();
            } else {
                $('.topBlock').fadeIn();
            }
        });

        // hide intro text onClick on list 
        $( "li" ).click(function() {
          $( ".topBlock" ).hide().animate();
        });

        var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
    //$j(".parallax_section_holder").css("height",$j(window).height()-116);
    //alert(viewportHeight);
```

I hope I have solved your issue, and if not, then please provide me the exact code link in jsfiddle.

Regards.